# Nginx proxy pass with redirect not working

Tags: nginx

I have a server with IP **192.168.1.10** and it installed a system called kubesphere,the access address is **http://192.168.1.10:30880**.

When we first visit it,it will redirect to a login page to let us login,after that we can go the homepage of it,the redirect code is similar to below(it ends with  a **slash**)

```
<a href="/login" target="_blank">Login</a>
```

Now I installed `nginx` on another server with ip **192.168.1.15**,and I want to access the system via `nginx`,thus I added code listed below:

```
  location  /kubesphere/ {
          proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.10:30880;

          proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
          proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_connect_timeout 600;
          proxy_send_timeout 600;
          proxy_read_timeout 600;
          send_timeout 600;
  }
```

But when I type **http://192.168.1.15/kubesphere** on browser,it will give me a **404 Not Found** response,checking `nginx` log I found below message

```
2023/09/05 15:09:54 [error] 51162#51162: *9802010 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/login" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

The **redirect** command is not redirect to **http://192.168.1.10/login** and it visit **/usr/share/nginx/html/login** instead,which make it not working as expected,the expected url is **http://192.168.1.10.30880/login** after using `proxy_pass`,but I can not do it myself.

I have tried a lot,including `chatGPT` and [**HoHoGPT**](https://www.hohogpt.com/) but still not get a solution,can anyone help me,please?

Thanks in advance!

---

Update:
An available test address is **http://182.92.238.5:30880/** ,we can use it for test!

I need to **http://192.168.1.15/kubesphere** ,which means the actual ip and port should never appear on the browser!

Comment: try to remove the trailing slash on location `location /kubesphere`  instead of `location /kubesphere/`

Comment: @GicuAftene, Thanks for your reply,I have tried it but still not working

Comment: Mhh ok, try instead to add a trailing slash on the proxyPass `http://192.168.1.10:30880/;` and also ensure that you realod nginx after the config update

Comment: @GicuAftene I have tried both and not working

Comment: I can't see any way, that your nginx instance would look for a local file if it goes into that location block. Can you have a look if it is listening on the correct server_name and port, and that there are no other config files loaded?

Comment: @Geilmaker It's has nothing to do with local file,the reason why it look for a local file it's due to my wrong configuration,that's why I posted this question for help

Comment: I guess you nginx config not works. Check if you have a default nginx config, and the nginx error log.

Comment: @LF00  I have provide an available address for test,you can test it in your side,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For your issue try Nginx rewrites instead of proxy passes.

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://182.92.238.5:30880/$1 permanent;
```

Below is the explanation;

1. ^/(.*)$: This is a regular expression pattern that matches any URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) path. Here's what it means:
   ^: Anchors the pattern to the start of the string.
   /: Matches the forward slash character, which is a common delimiter in URIs.
   (.*): This part is a capturing group ((...)), and .* matches zero or more of any character (.) except a newline. This effectively captures any string of characters that follow the initial forward slash.

   So, this regular expression captures the entire URI path.
2. http://182.92.238.5:30880/$1: This is a redirect URL. It specifies where the server should send the client's request after matching the regular expression pattern.
   http://182.92.238.5:30880/: This is the base URL where the request will be redirected.
3. $1: This is a backreference to the captured group from the regular expression. In this case, it refers to the entire URI path that was captured by (.*). The captured path will be appended to the base URL.
4. permanent;: This part specifies the type of HTTP redirect. In this case, it's a "permanent" redirect, which means the client's browser will cache this redirect and use it for subsequent requests to the same URI.

Putting it all together, this configuration rule is saying:

"Redirect any URI path (^/(.*)$) to http://182.92.238.5:30880/ followed by the captured path ($1), and make this redirect permanent."

For example, if a client requests http://example.com/some/path, it will be permanently redirected to http://182.92.238.5:30880/some/path.

So, finally, replace your location block with below,

```
 location  /kubesphere/ {
          rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://182.92.238.5:30880/$1 permanent;
          proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
          proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_connect_timeout 600;
          proxy_send_timeout 600;
          proxy_read_timeout 600;
          send_timeout 600;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but the redirect address `http://182.92.238.5:30880/some/path` is not what I want, I need to remove the port `30880` to let it never appear on the browser

Comment: @flyingfox  did you try changing the href attribute value?

Comment: Which `href` attribute do you mean? It's an third party software and I do not have access to modify it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the test address, that was actually pretty helpful.

Your problem is not related to nginx. The reverse proxy part is working fine, nginx gets the request and forwards it to the application successfully. Then the application sends a redirect to `/login`. That means that the browser does exactly this, it redirects to `<host>/login`. To solve your problem, you need to let kubesphere know, that it is running on a subpath (`/kubesphere`) so it can create its redirects accordingly (`<host>/kubesphere/login`). Unfortunatly I couldn't find any easy way to do this by just using google, but I'm also not into the kubesphere software. Maybe these information help you to solve the problem. If you find a way to tell kubesphere it's running on a subpath, it will create the correct redirects and it will be working fine.

Currently the redirects will only work when kubesphere is running on the root path. An option would be to work with subdomains, in case you will work with domains and not IP addresses.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You might want to have a look at that one: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/5017#issuecomment-601672968